# Join, rename and clear (compact) columns on sql select

Tags: mysql, sql

On excel I consult a table from the MySQL server and then modify the format of how the data is shown. I'm currently changing the SQL so the data comes already the way I want and one part is like this:

There's 25 columns named operator1-5lot1-5 (1-5 as in 1 to 5) like this:

`operator1lot1`, `operator2lot1`, `operator3lot1`, `operator4lot1`, `operator5lot1`, `operator1lot2`, `operator2lot2`, `operator3lot2`, `operator4lot2`, `operator5lot2`, `operator1lot3`, `operator2lot3`, `operator3lot3`, `operator4lot3`, `operator5lot3`, `operator1lot4`, `operator2lot4`, `operator3lot4`, `operator4lot4`, `operator5lot4`, `operator1lot5`, `operator2lot5`, `operator3lot5`, `operator4lot5`, `operator5lot5`.

`operator1lot1` has always a value, then each next operator can have a value if the ones behind also have (if `operator4lot1` has a value so do operators 1 to 3 of lot 1) and the same way to operator1lotX (if `operator1lot3` has a value so does operator 1 of lots 1 and 2 but doesn't mean that operators 2 to 5 of lots 1 and 2 have a value).

(not having a value means it's `NULL`)

Currently on excel I `SELECT` all the 25 columns, then join the values to the left side if there's space (if `operator2lot3` is `NULL` the value of `operator3lot3` is moved to there, to the left) then I delete the columns that are empty (that have all its values `NULL`) from the right side of the table to the left and finally I rename the columns from the left to the right to `1` to `x` (2 <= x <= 25).

Here's an example to explain it better. The database table looks like this:

[image: MySQL table]

And on Excel it formats to this:

[image: Excel table]

My question is if it is possible to format the data like that in the SQL directly. I don't know many SQL commands so the closest I can find that doesn't exactly do what I want is [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql) and [AS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

Comment: That's not a database table. That's a spreadhseet :-(

Comment: How do you get this data? Makes more sense to me to apply this on `insert` or `update`.

Comment: @Strawberry It's the table on the MySQL server (viewed with the program HeidiSQL).

Comment: @PeterM From Excel I connect to the database and use `SELECT`.

Comment: Oh it might be on a database. But it's not a database table. At a minimum, a database table would normally be normalised to 3NF. This is not normalised. We could probably help you fix that, if that was something you wanted to do, but we'd need to know why, for instance, '338' appears alongside '303' as opposed to '129'. On the other hand, if you didn't want to fix the structure of the database schema, then this isn't really a mysql/sql question.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand what you mean exactly. I have a server with a database that has a table that has some data and on Excel I get that data and format it to be more readable. I'm trying to get the data already formated instead so it doesn't have to run so much VBA code (on Excel) everytime I update the table.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but what you want is iterate all the values no matter what column they are in to first available column from left to right.  A column being available means it holds a value of `NULL`.

Comment: @PeterM Yes. Also just to make sure it was understood, I'm not updating the table from Excel, I'm only reading the values (`SELECT`). The table is filled from a web page.

Comment: @PeterM Maybe by first using [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql) and then [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) but I don't know, I'm not experienced with SQL to make a compact formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've stated before this is probably easier to do with the script generating the actual Excel file.

Anyway I do have a solution, it does not look pretty and I'm not sure this is the ideal approach but here goes.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 0 
        THEN substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',1 )
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col1,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 1 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',2 ),',',-1) 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col2,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 2 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',3 ),',',-1)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col3,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 3 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',4 ),',',-1)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col4,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 4 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',5 ),',',-1)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col5,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 5 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',6 ),',',-1)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col6,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 6 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',7 ),',',-1)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col7,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 7 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',8 ),',',-1)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col8,
    CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 8 
        THEN substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',9 ),',',-1)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS col9
FROM 
    (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`,`col9`) AS `combinedCols` FROM `tableName`) AS `tableNameAlias`;
```

For my example I've only put it 9 columns but extending this to 25 or more shouldn't be to hard once you understand what I've done.

#### Step 1

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`,`col9`) AS `combinedCols` FROM `tableName`
```

First we need to combine all columns, for that we can use `CONCAT_WS`, the first parameter of this function is the glue we're going to use in this case `,`.

#### Step 2

```
substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',1 )
```

Now we need to somehow explode these values on the `,` using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` we can separate the value on a specified character end on the specified occurrence.

#### Step 3

```
substring_index(substring_index(`combinedCols`,',',2 ),',',-1)
```

After passing the first occurrence we need to get fetch the last occurrence of the, in this case, second occurrence therefore we execute the same function again but now with a negative value of `-1`.

#### Step 4

```
CASE WHEN (char_length(`combinedCols`) - char_length(replace(`combinedCols`, ',', '')) + 1) > 1
```

Th last part is checking whether there are actually enough values to check for. This part counts the amount of used `,` and if sufficient executes the code otherwise simply sets a value of `NULL`

Well then hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

By way of example, and considering only the first 3 columns, and first 3 rows of data, a normalized schema might consist of 4 or 5 columns, as follows:

```
id operator lot entry value
 1        1   1     1  117
 2        1   1     2  117 
 3        1   1     3  129 
 4        2   1     1  319
 5        2   1     2  319
 6        3   1     2  530
```

The surrogate primary key id is not strictly necessary, because a satisfactory PK exists in the next 3 columns.